# retrieve data from two tables of a database and show it using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have created a database named (insert) having two tables table1 and table 2.

`table1` have 3 columns `user, id, roll`.

`table2` have 2 columns `id, menu`.

I have inserted values in two  tables.  I want to retrieve all values from two tables and show them in another php file, but my query is not working.  It's showing error.  What should I do?  here is my code

```
<?php

include 'insertjoincon.php';
$sql = "SELECT table1.user, id FROM table1, table2 WHERE    table1.id=table2.id";

echo "<table border=1>\n<tr><th>Name</th><th>ID</th></tr>\n";

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name = $line["user"];
    $id = $line["id"];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PZvvU4Va here is the information of two table

Comment: why are you using the obsolete `mysql_query` if you have `$conn` defined above?

Comment: sorry i did not get it..

Comment: Is there a relationship between these two tables?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error: SELECT table1.user, id FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id=table2.id
Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jointwo.php on line 14

Comment: You have to put an alias on the `id` column, it exists on both tables.

Comment: your databse schema is not clear - what is relation between those 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: The first few sentences are incorrect. In my first glance I saw that you specified a table for one column but missed that you didn't specify a table for `id`. Because they share the same value, pick one table and specify it. You should always specify table with either explicit or implicit JOINS. Still, first thing's first).

I'm guessing your query actually works if you test it. There is nothing inherently wrong with your query (although I always recommend using explicit `JOINS`).

There is a good reason why the example code you're providing would not work...

You're missing `$result = mysqli_query($sql):`

Yok can then use `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`.

`mysqli_fetch_array()` expects a result, not a SQL string.

Please note that you should use `mysqli` not `mysql`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the query to

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.user, table1.id FROM table1, table2 WHERE    table1.id=table2.id";
```

Comment: Technically yes, but why `FROM table1, table2` ? It seems that OP database badly designed

Comment: I have only modified the query. table1.id was missing, which would have probably given the error

Answer (score 2):

You need unique identifiers (aliases) for your tables:

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.user, t1.id FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id";
```

Possibly better would be a LEFT JOIN:

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.user, t1.id FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id";
```

Comment: imo you should explain why you use `LEFT` instead of `INNER` though

Comment: OP: "I want to retrieve all values from two tables" ---

LEFT would be the minimum way to do this; INNER wouldn't show rows unless both tables had matches.  I suppose in the strictest sense "all values" might actually require an OUTER join, but I'd sure as heck make sure I really wanted all those values returned before I recommend an OUTER JOIN to anyone ....

Comment: now query is working but this portion is creating problem                   while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$name  = $line["user"];
$id= $line["id"];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $name  . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
}  it is showing warning Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jointwo.php on line 14

Comment: Look at the return from the database.  You probably need to alias the returned columns also:

    $sql = "SELECT t1.user as theUSER, t1.id as theID FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id";

    $id = $line['theID'];
    $name = $line['theUSER'];

Comment: You are welcome.  I'm curious though, if this helped (apparently twice), why did you accept the other answer, which admittedly didn't get it quite right the first time?